# A and B complex self-adjoint, A positive semi-definite, then all eigenvalues of AB are real

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$, $B$ $\in$ $M_n\mathbb{(C)}$ be self-adjoint, and assume that $A$ is positive semidefinite; prove that all eigenvalues of $AB$ are real.

I've seen similar questions ([$T,U$ self-adjoint, $U$ positive definite, then $TU$ has only real eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267109/t-u-self-adjoint-u-positive-definite-then-tu-has-only-real-eigenvalues?rq=1)) but it seems that their proofs required the eigenvalues of $A$ to be strictly positive, and I don't konw how to deal with this issue here.

Comment: It should be noted exactly where the issue of $A$ being positive semi-definite becomes an issue in the linked source. It's not in computing the matrix square root of $A$: If self-adjoint $A$ has nonnegative eigenvalues, then $A=QDQ^*$ for unitary $Q$ and nonnegative diagonal $D$. So $A^{1/2}=Q D^{1/2}Q^*$ will be valid. But this can be singular, so the decomposition $AB=A^{-1/2} (A^{1/2}B A^{1/2})A^{1/2}$ isn't possible. Thus the impediment lies in step 2 of the linked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that [eigenvalues are invariant under cyclic permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281016/invariance-of-eigenvalues-of-a-product-of-square-matrices-under-cyclic-permutati), i.e, $\sigma(AB) = \sigma(BA)$ where $\sigma(X)$ denotes the set of eigenvalues of $X$. Then all we need to do is note
$$
\sigma(AB) = \sigma(A^{1/2}A^{1/2} B) = \sigma(A^{1/2} B A^{1/2})
$$
but $\sigma(A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}) \in \mathbb{R}$ as $A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!